# Como aplicar resplandor a un div?

Tags: javascript

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***Si se fijan este texto tiene un resplandor, como puedo aplicar ese mismo resplandor en `css`? a un div?***

***Sin box shadow***

*Por ejemplo, siempre es aplicado a un div o texto los métodos clásicos de css, que son `box-shadow` y `text-shadow`*, pero como se realizaría **sin esto**?, *claramente no puedo dar un ejemplo porque no encuentro otro método, de todas formas se agradecen las correciones*.

Comment: En [Codepen](https://codepen.io/tag/text-shadow/) tienes muchos ejemplos, por ejemplo [este](https://codepen.io/emaresko/pen/BlGIE?page=15) es algo parecido a lo que quieres.

Comment: Con la reputación que tienes deberías saber como funciona el sitio, pero veo no has realizado el [tour], revisa también por favor [ask].

Comment: Si es un div tiene que ser con el box-shadow y si es a un texto text-shadow, no hay mas creo yo :S

Comment: Ya lo edité, no puedo dar un ejemplo porque googleando ni aún encuentro un método sin usar box ni text shadow

Comment: Porqué no quieres utilizar `text-shadow`? Esa es la manera correcta de hacerlo.

Comment: Para aprender, como será posible que solo exista 1 forma?

Comment: Aunque puede que se pueda hacer de otra forma, es una buena práctica usar las cosas para lo que han sido creadas, en el caso del resplandor del texto es con text-shadow

Answer (score 1):

```
h1 {
    text-shadow: 2px 4px 8px blue;
}
```

La sombra será desplazada a la derecha 2px, separada hacia abajo 4px y con un difuminado ( si podemos llamarlo así ) de 8px.

Para que quede algo parecido a la imagen que has puesto y la sombra salga desde el centro tienes que tener el desplazamiento a 0px 0px

Juega con las medidas de los px y con el color para adaptarlo a tu gusto.

> **Nota:** No soportado en Internet explorer 9 o versiones anteriores.

```css
body {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}

h1 {
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px yellow;
}
```

```html
<h1>Esto es un título</h1>
```

Comment: Puedes hacer un snippet de codigo para probar la funcinoalidad de tu respuesta? ^^